# What does this compiler error means - "qualified-id in declaration before ‘=’ token" in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to understand the usage of private const in the class.
My understanding is that private const is used to make something constant within the class and static to have one copy.

Initially, my code was using pi and it's data type was float. So, I tried changing the float to int because I read const static is only allowed for int types within class.

```
#include <iostream>
class MyExample
{

 private:
   static const int x;

};

int main(void)
{
  int const  MyExample::x = 3;

  std::cout<<"x value is "<<MyExample::x<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

compiling -

```
$g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:12:27: error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘=’ token
   int const  MyExample::x = 3;
```

I know that moving the line " int const  MyExample::x = 3;" from main() to outside, removes error if I remove private also.

Comment: Aside: Since C++20 there is [`std::numbers::pi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants) (or `std::numbers::pi_v<float>` if you really want a `float` not a `double`)

Comment: What is a reason behind, you use "private" member variable to "static" and calling outside of the Class?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, but when I put static member initialization out of main function, the problem is solved, like this:

```
int const  MyExample::x = 3;
int main(){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

because the variable ' x'  is private access modifier, that means variable x used only in the class. So you can't use that variable in main function.

and there is 2 suggestion.

first, make getter, setter method.

second, change to public access modifier.

thanks

Comment: If you have getter and setter, you might as well make the variable public, not private. It is effectively public anyway.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about initialising static members

Answer (score 0):

`MyExample::x` is a [qualified-id](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers) and you have placed it in a declaration before the `=` token. This is not allowed at block scope.

Comment: Your answer to his question is to essentially quote the error back to him? This is entirely unhelpful. Explain what it is he should do. Don't simply rephrase the error.

Comment: @Cerin please read the title, it is literally asking what the error means. My answer explains the meaning of terms in the error message in case they didn't understand those terms .

Comment: Also they explain in the body that they know how to fix the problem (move the line to be outside of `main`).